# Applying a NSPredicate to a to-many relationship returns 0 values

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Assuming the entity `Store` with **to-many** relationship with my entity `Offer` (`Offer` <<---- `Store`)

[image: Store relationships]

I want to fetch all of my stores containing at least a specific offer.

So I tried this :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY offers.offerID == %@", _offer.offerID];
```

Log of the generated SQL request :

```
details: SQLite bind[0] = "51dbc2b94eb8dd9a7d00000d"
2014-01-09 11:30:11.169 ****[39542:70b] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0011s
2014-01-09 11:30:11.170 ****[39542:70b] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0xd50f3a0> on entity 'Store' with sql text 'SELECT DISTINCT t0.Z__AF_RESOURCEIDENTIFIER FROM ZSTORE t0 JOIN ZOFFER t1 ON t0.Z_PK = t1.Z7OFFERS WHERE  t1.ZOFFERID = ? ORDER BY t0.ZORDERNUMBER LIMIT 24' returned 0 rows with values: (
)
```

but it seems that it does not work.

However I'm sure that stores contain my offer, because when I fetch **ALL** stores (without predicate), here is the log of the store I get:

```
<Store: 0x12149350> (entity: Store; id: 0xd6bb210 <x-coredata://135F3A30-4BC6-4428-8D19-8D3EEBBE8173-39447-0000BC0D17888C74/Store/p__af_5097ffad4eb8dd720d02211f> ; data: {
    {…}
    offers =     (
        "0x12145c20 <x-coredata://135F3A30-4BC6-4428-8D19-8D3EEBBE8173-39447-0000BC0D17888C74/Offer/p__af_offer_51dbc2b94eb8dd9a7d00000d>"
    );
    {…}
})
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What happens if you fetch all objects and then filter the array using that predicate? Does that give the expected result? - And you should really add the inverse relationships. I don't know if it fixes *this* problem, but there are more reasons.

Comment: @MartinR if number of objects is too large, its will increase too much memory usage. Its not the preferred way.

Comment: @santhu: That was only meant to isolate the problem, not as the final solution.

Comment: @MartinR Filtered array with predicate does not work. My array contain 20 objects and the filtered array contain 0 object.

Comment: Could you say something on `offerID`? In addition following @MartinR advice I would log all the `offerID`' offers in your store and verify if that the one you're looking for exists.

Comment: In other words, if your array contains 20 objects, log its values. Also be sure that `_offer.offerID` looks correct.

Comment: @Jipé: If filtering the fetched array also gives 0 objects then there is no object matching the fetch request.

Answer (score 2):

You should have an inverse relationship from Offer to Store. Then you fetch the Offer by offerID and access the Store in the code simply by accessing the store property of the offer.

I suspect this would be easier on the database than using ANY in the predicate.

You can even improve this a little. If you specify your inverse relationship from offer to store as a relationship for prefetching when fetching offer, you’ll save one trip to database when accessing `offer.store` after the fetch.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the advices given by @MartinR (in comments). It appears that the offers were corrupted and had a *nil* `offerID`.

The @Alexei answer didn't solve my problem but following his advice was a good clue, namely creating an inverse relationship from Offer to Store.

Comment: Following the advice from Alexei probably solved your corruption.  Not having an inverse relationship (and ignoring the warning as well) is a recipe for disaster in Core Data.  Those relationships are needed.

Comment: I'm agree, and it's why I followed his advice and I created an inverse relationship:)

Comment: Are you sure that it didn’t solve your problem? It should work and also should do it faster.